# Emacs init with spacemacs fails all the time - Error connection time out for melpa repository

Tags: spacemacs, microsoft-windows, package-repositories

I installed GNU Emacs 25.2.1 64bit and downloaded spacemacs the way it is described in their git repo.

Now when starting up through `runemacs.exe` the following output occurs:

```
Warning (spacemacs): 
Error connection time out for melpa repository!
Warning (spacemacs): 
Error connection time out for gnu repository!
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘c:/Users/p.hoefer/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/init.el’:

File error: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, bind-map

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Googling for this problem showed me it is a common issue but the solution there did not worked for me - or I am too stupid to use them right.

Comment: Which Emacs build are you using? I had the same problems when I was using a build without GnuTLS, but when I switched to a build from http://emacsbinw64.sourceforge.net/ they disappeared.

Comment: emacs-25.2-x86_64.zip - thats the one I loaded

Comment: Can you try running it with the `--insecure`-flag on the commandline? That might help.

Comment: It was the binary problem - the one from sourceforge worked!

Comment: I don't know about you, but I think a setup where starting Emacs connects to remote hosts is a very bad idea, e.g. for performance reasons, for reasons of use when disconnected, for reasons of security, and on and on and on.  I suggest you report this as a bug.